# Create an array in specific format so it displays result in the dropdown - php

Tags: php, arrays

I just got a job as a junior php developer and I am trying to solve a problem. I need to print out result in a dropdown and the existing function that does that is returning result like this:

```
return [1 => 'test'];
```

Now it is returning value 'test' in the dropdown. What I need to do is to create that format in foreach to print out all categories in the dropdown.
Something like this:

```
$cat = '';
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $cat = array($category->getId() => $category->getName());
}
return $cat;
```

But now I get only the last result. How can I make it show all the categories?
When I print

```
$category->getId()
```

i get:

```
string(2) "76"
```

and for

```
$category->getName()
```

i get:

```
string(3) "Men"
```

I tried appending the cat variable but then i get blank screen:

```
$cat .= array($category->getId() => $category->getName());
```

Please help me find the solution to the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is an array of arrays, so change your loop to something like this:

```
$cat = array();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    $cat[] = array($category->getId() => $category->getName());
}
return $cat;
```

This will give you an array that looks like this:

```
[[1 => 'test'],[76 => 'Men']];
```

You may then need to modify how you handle the return since it's now a multi-dimensional array, but that is the proper format for the data you're wanting to return.

Comment: Yep I did that, problem is that I don't know how to handle the return, whatever I do I get the blank screen, no error_log, nothing. :(

Comment: Without seeing your code that handles the return, I'm not sure what to do. Can you add that code to your question?

Comment: I have solved this by converting multidimensional array to single dim array:


    return array_reduce($cat, 'array_merge', array());

Thank you @Nick Coons.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this but one simple one comes to mind. Put your foreach loop straight inside the dropdown and echo out the results right there (not into a variable for later useage)   Something like:
echo "< option >$category->getId() < / option >";

Comment: There is no frontend in this case. I don't have the access to the option tag. It is all dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by converting multidimensional array to single dim array:

```
return array_reduce($cat, 'array_merge', array());
```

Thank you @Nick Coons.